# Оператор if в Android Studio

Tags: java, android, if

Что я не так делаю? Почему показывает false

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Заменил == на equals(). Решил проблему

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Используйте вместо `==` - `equals()`